# django.contrib.auth extends User with Profil error "No column id"

Tags: django

I use django.contrib.auth and extend it with a OneToOne profil.

A couple days ago all was working, but today I cant access profil from `user.profil`, and my model dont work, I keep getting error `Django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column users_profil.id`

Why?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profil(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    facebook_profil = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="")
```

And I cant access profil

```
>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>> from users.models import Profil
>> user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
>> user.pk
1
>> user.profil 
Django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column users_profil.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming profil is a Profil object that was created with a onetoone relationship to that pk=1 user, shouldn't the syntax be the other way around? I tried recreating this, and get your error with `user.profil`, but get this the other way around:

```
>>> profil.user
<User: admin>
>>> profil.user.pk
1
```

Comment: onetoone works in both way. You can access profil with user.profil and you can access user with profil.user

Answer (score 0):

Because this feature have relation to contenttypes app，I guess you have not add the app that Profil model is in to Install Apps settings。